# how do i run a custom function on a string instead of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

As a test I wrote this fn which works:

```
$.fn.doubleup = function(){
    this.html(this.html()*2);
};

$('div').doubleup();
```

I tried to write a similar function to run on a number like below, but this doesn't work:

```
$.fn.doubleup2 = function(){
    this = (this * 2);
};

var n = 2;

n.doubleup2();
```

Is it possible to write a fn that runs on variables or strings?

Answer (score 4):

In your scenario, I wouldn't use jQuery at all. If you want to double up on say, numbers, then try using the [Number.prototype](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_prototype_num.asp) property.

```
Number.prototype.doubleUp = function() {
    return this * 2;
}

var num = 23;
console.log(num.doubleUp());
```

JavaScript already has great support for you to extend types with your own functionality, there is no need to use jQuery here.

EDIT:

Based on the comments, you could do this:

```
Object.prototype.doubleUp = function () {
    if (this instanceof Number) {
        return this * 2;
    }

    if (this instanceof String) {
        return this * 4; // Just for example.
    }

    return this * 2; // Just for example.
};

var num = 23;
var num2 = "23";
console.log(num.doubleUp());
console.log(num2.doubleUp());
```

Comment: This will raise a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: is there a way to extend all non 'objects'? i want to execute on all.. then check integer, string e.t.c....

Comment: @Mchl Yeah, sorry, poor example, wasn't thinking straight. Have changed the code so that it actually works now :)

Comment: @partebena What do you mean all non objects exactly? Do you just want to doubleUp() on string and numbers only?

Comment: @JasonEvans he wahts to be able to do `$('#test').doubleup2()` same as `someVar.doubleup2();`

Comment: lets say for example run doubleUp() on a null object and check if it's null or a number or a string or an object

Comment: Most basic types are boxed (that is turned into an object) when you invoke a method on them, but `null` and `undefined` are special and cannot be boxed and cannot be called with method syntax. If the result `$('div`) is `null` an exception will be thrown.